# ruby on rails : check table value from javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

How people can check the value of a table from javascript. I am using ruby on rails. I did this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ("<%= @player.name %>" == "" ) {
   //show some divs
  } 
});
```

But it doesn't work. Even the player's name is empty, the divs don't showed.
I want to check if the player's name is empty, then it should show some divs.
Thanks.

Comment: [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript)?

Comment: would you mind to elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you're using `<%` instead of `<%=`. Secondly, suppose `@player.name` is `john` then your javascript code will be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (john == "") {
   //show some divs
  } 
});
```

See the problem? Your `@player.name` will be regarded as a javascript variable (which doesn't exist), not as a string.

Lastly, if your `@player.name` should contain a double-quote your javascript will be broken again, so you have to escape it with `escape_javascript`.

Solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ("<%= j @player.name %>" == "") {
   //show some divs
  } 
});
```

Comment: sorry my mistake. I did quote the <% @player.name  %>. I'll edit my question

Comment: @takodil Please look at the other remarks. This answer should still solve your question.

Comment: yes, I tried it already. The divs still doesn't showed, but when I tried it with alert, it worked. So I think, it's another mistake then. Thanks for your answer :-)

Comment: @takodil You're welcome. Good luck finding the actual problem.